# Exporting const from a fucntion in React into another component?

Tags: reactjs, export

I have a file ButtonExample.js that I am exporting a component (ButtonExample) and const (color) from. I am attempting to import them into a file called CustomCreation.js. However, on compiling I am met with the error:

*Attempted import error: 'color' is not exported from './ButtonExample'.*

This is the code for ButtonExample.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { GithubPicker } from "react-color";

function ButtonExample() {
  const [showColorPicker, setShowColorPicker] = useState(false);
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-dark"
        onClick={() =>
          setShowColorPicker((showColorPicker) => !showColorPicker)
        }
      >
        {showColorPicker ? "Close" : "Choose Color"}
      </button>
      {showColorPicker && (
        <div>
          <GithubPicker
            color={color}
            onChange={(updatedColor) => setColor(updatedColor.hex)}
            colors={[
              "#131313" /*black*/,
              "#575757" /*grey*/,
              "#f6f6f6" /*white*/,
              "#203e20" /*green*/,
              "#423122" /*brown*/,
              "#121c4f" /*navy*/,
            ]}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default { ButtonExample, color };
```

This is how I'm attempting to import it in CustomCreation.js

```
import ButtonExample, { color } from "./ButtonExample";
```

I've done this in the past and it's worked fine so I'm just unsure if I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: For once color variable hook is inside ButtonExample function component, meaning it's undefined outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

`color` is declared as state inside the scope of the `ButtonExample()` functional component, so when you try to access it inside `export default { ButtonExample, color };` it'll always be undefined.

Moreover, your export and import syntax seems incorrect. A [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) defines a *single export* per module, so what you're essentially doing here is exporting an object comprised of `ButtonExample` and an undefined variable and attempting to use *both* named and default imports to import them.

To better share state between your components, you should either use a **state manager** like Redux to manage state globally throughout your application or implement a **parent component** for this component and any other component that relies on the current color. The parent component will then manage the color state and pass that down as a prop to any other components that need it. Additionally, the parent component will need to implement its own `setColor` function that it passes to `ButtonExample` as a prop, which can then be substituted for `GithubPicker's` `onChange` callback.